# MSH Flex Grid VB6 - formatting

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I'm working with a MSH FlexGrid in VB6. I have a Stored Procedure that pulls this data from SQL Server. For some of the values `"sex"` I save the value as either `0` or `1` - `0` for Male `1` for Female. When I populate the flex grid, I'd like it to show `MALE` or `FEMALE` rather than `0` or `1`. Additionally, the Date of Birth that gets populated in the FLEX GRID has Time next to it. How would I fix that?

```vb
With Me.fgrdClient
     Set Me.fgrdClient.DataSource = rs
    .FormatString = "|<First Name|<MI|<Last Name|<Sex|<DOB"
    .ColWidth(0, 0) = 0        'Column label
    .ColWidth(1, 0) = 1500        'First
    .ColWidth(2, 0) = 1000        'MI
    .ColWidth(3, 0) = 1500        'LAST
    .ColWidth(4, 0) = 1600        'SEX
    .ColWidth(5, 0) = 1000        'DOB
End With
```

Comment: How would this work if I needed to fix the date so it was only MM/DD/YYYY. It keeps showing up as Date & Time for DOB

Comment: To format your date try `CONVERT(varchar(10), DOB, 101) AS DOB`

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly!!!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT [First Name], MI, [Last Name],
    CASE 
      WHEN Sex=1 THEN 'Male'
      WHEN Sex=2 THEN 'Female'
      ELSE 'Unknown'
    END
    , DOB  
FROM `myTable`
```